# Undefined variable: success_message

Tags: codeigniter

How to fix this error message?

---

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: success_message
>
> Filename: views/editclients.php
>
> Line Number: 40
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\EcommerceGiondaCI\application\views\editclients.php
>   Line: 40 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\EcommerceGiondaCI\application\controllers\Cpages.php
>   Line: 343 Function: view
>
> File: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\EcommerceGiondaCI\index.php
>   Line: 315 Function: require_once

views/editclients.php

```
                <?php echo $success_message; ?>

                <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

                <?php foreach ($clients as $clients_item): ?>

                <div class="widget-box">
                    <div class="widget-title"><h5>Parent Categories</h5></div>
                    <div class="widget-content">

                    <?php echo form_open('cpages/editclientsupdate/'.$clients_item['client_id']); ?>
                    <table border="0" style="width: 80%; height: 90px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>FIRST NAME</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="newsletter" value="<?php echo $clients_item['client_firstname']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>LAST NAME</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="newsletter" value="<?php echo $clients_item['client_lastname']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ADDRESS LINE1</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="newsletter" value="<?php echo $clients_item['client_addressline1']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ADDRESS LINE2</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="newsletter" value="<?php echo $clients_item['client_addressline2']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CELLPHONE</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="newsletter" value="<?php echo $clients_item['client_cellphone']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>STATE</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="newsletter" value="<?php echo $clients_item['client_state']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CITY</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="newsletter" value="<?php echo $clients_item['client_city']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>COUNTRY</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="newsletter" value="<?php echo $clients_item['client_country']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>EMAIL</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="newsletter" value="<?php echo $clients_item['client_email']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>MOBILE</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="newsletter" value="<?php echo $clients_item['client_cellphone']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>STATUS</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="newsletter" value="<?php echo $clients_item['client_status']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" class="edit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"></td>
                        </tr>   
                    </table>            
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

controllers/Cpages.php

```
public function editclientsupdate() {


    $client_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $data['clients'] = $this->pages_model->call_clients_point($client_id);

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('client_firstname', 'Client First Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('client_lastname', 'Client Last Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('client_addressline1', 'Client Address Line1', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('client_addressline2', 'Client Address Line2', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('client_cellphone', 'Client Cell Phone', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('client_state', 'Client State', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('client_city', 'Client City', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('client_country', 'Client Country', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('client_email', 'Client Email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('client_cellphone', 'Client Cellphone', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('client_status', 'Client Status', 'required');


  if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {   // return to first 

        $data['success_message'] = "";

        $this->load->view('editclients', $data);

    }   
    else
    {
        $data['success_message'] = "Setting has been successfully updated!";    


        $this->pages_model->update_clients($client_id);

        $this->load->view('editclients', $data);

    }   

}
```

Comment: At what point does the error occur. Is it on first page load? Admittedly from your code it looks like you are setting it.

Comment: Yes, on the first page load.

Comment: The form validation ->run returns a boolean TRUE or FALSE. Try changing the IF test to == FALSE, instead of ===FALSE. Does that change the behaviour? I am not sure this is the cause hence answering in a comment.

Comment: You could just use an if(!empty($success_message)) echo $success_message but I would not really advocate fixing the outcome without understanding why it is happening in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It is a notice error because on your page sometimes success_message variable is not declared, use the following code

```
<?php if (isset($success_message)) { echo $success_message; } ?>
```